# How to do multiple files upload on webpage and save on disk in web.py?

Tags: python-2.7, web.py

I was following LPTHW ex51 by Zed shaw http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex51.html,  and was doing his study drills on web.py , i am a web.py beginner and  was successful in uploading an image on Webpage form and then storing it in a local folder. The issue is each image I store , replaces the earlier one. Also I cant figure out how to upload multiple images on server and store them all.

Here is my class Upload in app.py:

```
class Upload(object):
    def GET(self):
        web.header("Content-Type","text/html; charset=utf-8")
        return render.upload()

    def POST(self):
        x= web.input(myfile={})
        filedir= "C:/Users/tejas/Documents/filesave"
        if 'myfile' in x:
            fout = open(filedir + '/' + 'myfile.jpg', 'wb') # creates the file where the uploaded file should be stored
            fout.write(x.myfile.file.read()) # writes the uploaded file to the newly created file.
            fout.close() # closes the file, upload complete
            return "Success! Your image has been saved in the given folder."
            raise web.seeother('/upload')
```

and my upload form- upload.html :

```
<html>
    <head><title>

    <div id="header" <h1 style="color:blue;">Upload image file</h1><div/>

    </title></head>

    <body background-color=light-blue,font-family=verdana,font-size=100%;>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
        <input type="file" name="myfile"/>

     <br/> <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

I tried searching a lot for similar questions but all in PHP , and so I try something similar with the code but I could not get it working. Any suggestions to improve the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason your code is replacing the earlier on is because your hardcoding the path to save the image

```
fout = open(filedir + '/' + 'myfile.jpg', 'wb')
```

everytime you upload the file to be altered is the same this could be corrected by adding an new name each time your uploading new file or extracting the name from web input

```
fout = open(filedir + '/' + x.myfile.filename, 'wb');
```

according to python when opening for writing files with the same name will be erased
make sure each new file you upload has different name from the previous uploaded

Comment: Thanks feels great to help